# If a Jew is Bar/bat mitzvah in Hanukkah may they light the menorah

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, orach-chaim

According to Halacha, if a Jew becomes bar/bat mitzvah during the middle of Hanukkah, is it permissible for them to light the menorah candles  with a beracha? Or since they weren’t obligated by the first Hanukkah lighting can they not fulfill the mitzvah during the later lightings?